# I can't load bitmaps on WinCE

Tags: .net, exception, compact-framework, resources, bitmap

I wrote a small project that displays icons on the screen on WinCE. The icons are 28x28 16-color BMP files, placed in the main resource file (Resources.resx) (the resx for the main Form has the same problem, and GIF files don't work either).

The first time I try to get any bitmap from the resources, an exception of type Exception with Message "Exception" is thrown from Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr, which was called from System.Drawing.Bitmap._InitFromMemoryStream.

I have two WinCE devices. This error only occurs on one of them; the other works fine. Other than this one problem, the app works on both devices. The app also uses some native code that involves DIBs, and that works fine. Any ideas?

Update: The same error occurs if I try to load a bitmap from a file. I also tried 1-bit (black & white), 8-bit and 24-bit bitmaps to no avail (WinCE framebuffers are most commonly 16-bit, but I have no image editor that can produce 16-bit bitmaps.)

Comment: What devices are these? Can you post links to the bitmaps?

Comment: Are these two devices running the same OS build? Or are they two distinct types of devices?

.NET CF relies upon OS provided image codecs. So it is possibly particular OS images may not support every file format detailed in the documentation.

Comment: You say you can create a DIB.  How about a DDB?  Does the failing device's display driver support a 16-color pallette?

Comment: Is there any sort of documentation about how .NET CF uses image-provided "codecs"?

Comment: I tried simply creating a DDB and DIB in the Compact Framework and both worked. See http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/PermaLink,guid,987041fc-2e13-4bab-930a-f79021225b74.aspx - the (w,h) constructor is supposed to create a DDB, the (w,h,pixelformat) constructor is supposed to create a DIB.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem and have been working on it for days. The next thing I am going to try is to store the bitmap as a DIB in the resource file, load it using LoadResource, convert it to a DDB by using GetCompatibleDC and "drawing" the DIB to the DC, that should create a DDB. I think the key is to use  CreateCompatibleBitmap. I will report back on my findings.

Comment: I hope you're writing this in C#... I'm pretty sure a C# resource file is different than a C++ resource file.